# How long should RAID 10 syncing stay at 'recovery = 99.9%'?

Tags: centos, raid, centos-7, software-raid, mdadm

After replacing a faulty disk in a (CentOS 7) RAID 10, the syncing is at the following stage for quite some time now;  it has had this state for more than a day:

```
md10 : active raid10 sdp1[9] sdo1[8](S) sdw[6] sdq[5] sdn[4] sdm[3] sdl[2] sdk[1] sdj[0]
      11720536064 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [8/7] [UUUUUUU_]
      [===================>.]  recovery = 99.9% (2930134016/2930134016) finish=0.0min speed=0K/sec
      bitmap: 88/88 pages [352KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Is that normal (I should be patient), or does it indicate a problem?

Comment: “…at the following stage for quite some time now…” What does this mean? A few hours? About a day? More than one day? Also what kind of data is stored on this RAID 10 array? Lots of small files can muck up the works and slow things down.

Comment: I had this state for more than a day, @Giacomo1968. After getting impatient, I rebooted the server, recreated the RAID, which is now syncing.

Comment: Thanks for the info! You should post that info on rebooting as an answer. Not the greatest solution, but sometimes that is what needs to be done to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

*The inelegant solution:*

I had this state of `recovery = 99.9%` for more than a day.

After getting impatient, I rebooted the server, recreated the RAID, which then started syncing.